# Bind Core to ocamldoc

Tags: ocaml, ocamldoc

I am trying to generate documentation for a module of mine using `ocamldoc`. However, I use the `Core` library and `ocamldoc` complains about not finding it.

```
Error: Unbound module Core
```

I understand why thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217840/why-does-ocamldoc-fail-on-unbound-modules), but it doesn't mention any solution for standard modules.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ocamldoc` needs to see the compiled interface for `Core`, i.e. the file `core.cmi`. This can be done through one of the following mechanisms:

- Add the `-I dir` option to `ocamldoc` where `dir` is the directory where the `core.cmi` file lies. So for example `ocamldoc -I $(opam config var core:lib) ...` should do.
- If you use the `ocamlfind` indirection, add `-package core` to the command line. E.g. `ocamlfind ocamldoc -package core`